# Difference between INPUT_GET and INPUT_POST

Tags: javascript, php, html, mootools

I have this line of code in my php file where I am have a question regarding the line of code. What would be the difference if I did this to verify my date variable?

**Retrieve.php**

```
$firstDate = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'dtDate', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

AND

```
$firstDate = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'dtDate', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

**html file**

```
   <form id="siteForm" action="#" name="siteForm">
    <input type="text" name="itemDate" id="itemDate" required>
   </form>
    <input type="submit" class="btn" id='Submit' value="Add" />
```

I am trying to use the $firstDate variable to compare to a date from the Database, but I need to have the date in an acceptable string format. Would one filter_input option be better than the other?

Mind you I am not using a post or get method in the  because I am using a java script file to encode the information.
 See below:

**Js. file**

```
function submit(){
     var formHash =  new Hash();
     $$('#siteForm input, #siteForm textarea, #siteForm input[type=submit]').each(function(el){
         var key = el.getProperty('id');
         var value = el.getPropert('value'.trim());
         formHash.set(key, value);

     });
     processManager.setOptions({
         data: {
             'encFormData': JSON.encode(formHash)
         }
     }).send();
}
```

**Any advice helps.**

Comment: If you don't set the method attribute in your form, it will default to 'GET', i.e. if you want to `filter_input()`, you need to use `INPUT_GET`, as the `$_POST` array won't contain your variable.

Comment: ah okay that makes sense.  In other words if I use the $_POST on any of these variables I would have had to declared the form as $_POST from the get go?